# Sails.js has socket.io issues on AWS, but not locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

I'm building an app called Tuftslife, and when running locally it works fine, but when I put it on AWS, it works for a little, outputs a lot of errors (like those below) and then crashes a little while later and only returns 500s. Our theory is that these requests are never timing out and overwhelming the server.

[image: The issue I'm having]

We tried turning off socket.io using this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mikermcneil/8911041) but it doesn't seem to have worked. What are we doing wrong?

Comment: What do the errors on the server look like?

Comment: What does your AWS setup look like? Are you using ELBs?

Comment: If you are using ELBs then you must configure sticky sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the entire file that does socket.io on the frontend ended up muting our issue. I don't know enough about these things to diagnose exactly what we were doing. Oh well, works now.